# CMAKE: Can I exclude a specific version when searching for a package with find_package?

Tags: cmake, package, libraries

In a project I am searching for a package with find_package. The project can work with a range of versions of the package - except for a single specific version, which has a unfixed bug which makes it unusable.

Is it possible to allow for a range of versions and exclude just a single one, like:

```
find_package(PACKAGE 1.0.0...1.5.0 EXCEPT 1.4.0 REQUIRED)
```

?

Edit: While there is certainly the option of printing out an error message when only the defective version is found, I am searching for a solution which just skips the defective version when finding multiple possible candidates on the system.

Answer (score 1):

I kind of found a (bit quirky) solution, which just works, but it may have side-effects which do not matter in case of my project:

```
find_package(PACKAGE 1.0.0...1.3.999 QUIET)
if (NOT PACKAGE_FOUND)
    find_package(PACKAGE 1.4.1...1.5.0 REQUIRED)
endif()
if (PACKAGE_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "PACKAGE ${PACKAGE_VERSION} found")
endif()
```